# Accessing SMART attributes in Linux with only Python?

Tags: python, linux, disk

Is there a way to do this without using smartmontools? I'd like to try to see how far I get with just Python if possible. A google search does not seem to yield too much.

Comment: You should probably install a C library that can access this low-level information and use it via `ctypes` or writing a C-Extension. There's *plenty* of tutorials/manuals on how to do this. If you are asking about "which C library to choose", then your question is off-topic and you should re-asked an in-topic question when you *try* to use a library and find some troubles.

Comment: Thanks for the tip; I am still trying to figure out if there is a way to do this without C libraries as well for now. Is there a way to do this without any other extensions?

Answer (score 3):

Get `libatasmart` which is a C library, and invoke it from Python via `ctypes` or `cffi`.